# How to order a "Routed to VLAN" portable subnet via SoftLayer API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

It seems that by default we get portable private subnet as "Secondary on VLAN", I am wondering whether we could order a "Routed to VLAN" portable private subnet via SL API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it's not possible to order this subnets "Routed to vlan" through API or order form. It needs to be executed manually by an employee and you will need to open a ticket for this please.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification